# showing mini graphs in listview react native

Tags: react-native, charts

I need to show data in graphical representation like stock app in itunes.
There are many libs but I cant find one giving such functionalities.
Can Any body suggest how to implement.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [React-native-svg-charts](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts)
which you can control size and colors

here is an [Example](https://snack.expo.io/@hassan190011/svg-charts)